# Ignoring invisible elements with :nth-child in selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of `<li>` elements, and I'm using `:nth-child` to target specific children of every 3rd and 4th element, and give them an additional class `.right`.

But, when I hide some elements (let's say, the first or second list item), it doesn't work properly. I want to add class "right" only to children of *visible* list items. How can I do that?

This is the code I'm using:

```
$(".ilist:visible:nth-child(4n+3)").find(".window").addClass("right");
$(".ilist:visible:nth-child(4n+4)").find(".window").addClass("right");
```

And I remove all classes `.right` with this:

```
$(".ilist .window.right").removeClass("right");
```

HTML structure:

```
<ul>
   <li class="ilist">
      ...
      <div class="name">Name (Search works with it)</div>
      <div class="window"></div>
   </li>

   ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Your problem isn't entirely clear. What happens when you "use search"? What is your HTML structure? What do you mean by "doesn't work properly"?

Comment: When I use search, then adding class .right work in random way. For example if elements is 8, then only one will get class .right.

Comment: What is "search"? Is it an element?

Comment: Are your `.window` elements the `nth-child`ren themselves, or descendants thereof? Maybe you're using `.find()` when you need `.is()`.

Comment: what do you mean with *but if I use search, then it doesn't work properly*

Comment: When I use search, then adding class .right work in random way. For example if elements is 8, then only one will get class .right.

Comment: `is()` don't work here, it's a problem with selectors. It work with wrong elements. For example it give class .right not for 3,4 element, but for 3 and 5 element.

Comment: But which elements are you trying to count here? The list items or the divs inside?

Comment: list items must be visible and div indide this element need to get a special class

Comment: I know, but does e.g. 4n+3 refer to the lis or the divs? Because your selector applies to the lis, and maybe you wanted it to be the divs?

Comment: This selector work properly, when list is loaded first time. But if some elements of list are `hide()`, then this selector work in random way without any logic.

Comment: nth-child just ignore that I use selector :visible.

Comment: You'll have to rethink your logic. The fact that you hide an element does not change its position in the DOM tree, so `nth-child(4n+3)` won't change if you hide any sibling.

Comment: Then how I can give for every visible 3rd and 4th element a special class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you hide an element does not change its position in the DOM tree, so `nth-child(4n+3)` won't change if you hide any sibling list item.

When you toggle the visibility some elements list items, you'll have to reset your `right` classes, and reapply to the appropriate elements.

You can do that by passing a function to `addClass`, instead of the new class name. This function will receive the index of the matched element as the first parameter, and you can use it to check if it's the 3rd or 4th. If it is, return the new class name you want to apply:

```
$(".ilist .window.right").removeClass("right");
$(".ilist:visible .window").addClass(function(i, currentClass){
    return (i == 2 || i == 3) ? "right" : "";
});
```

Live demo at http://jsfiddle.net/6TMmJ/

Answer (score 2):

To add a class to the children of every nth visible list item, you can first find all visible list items, then filter those by their rank within the collection:

```
$(".ilist:visible").filter(function(index){
    return (index % 4 == 0) || (index % 4 == 3);
}).find(".window").addClass("right");
```